# fitted values for every case in dataset with emmeans

Tags: r, lm, emmeans

I'm trying to get `disp` predictions for each observation in `mtcars` with `emmeans`. I can get average `disp` predictions with:

```
library(emmeans)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = mtcars)
emm <- emmeans(mod, "disp", at=list(disp=c(130,135,140)))
```

However, is it possible to get the fitted values for every single case in the dataset, similar to what I get with `predict(mod)`?

EDIT:
Ben Bolker suggested this:

```
nd <- expand.grid(hp = unique(mtcars$hp), disp = 130)
mean(predict(mod, newdata = nd))
23.20037
```

However, this doesn't match the average I get in emmeans:

```
emmeans(mod, "disp", at=list(disp=130))

disp emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
  130   23.1 0.928 29     21.2       25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```r
nd <- expand.grid(hp = unique(mtcars$hp), disp = c(130,135,140))
predict(mod, newdata = nd)
```

?

(or skip the `unique()` if you really want predictions for every observation even if they have non-unique `hp` ...)

If you want a predicted frame whose mean matches `emmeans`, you do want to skip the `unique()`.  If you only want to consider a single value of `disp`, you don't need the `expand.grid`:

```r
nd <- data.frame(hp = mtcars$hp, disp = 130)
mean(predict(mod, newdata = nd))
## [1] 23.14716
```

Comparing with `emmeans` (convert to data frame so we can see full resolution)

```r
as.data.frame(emmeans(mod, "disp", at=list(disp=130)))
 disp   emmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL
  130 23.14716 0.9283063 29 21.24856 25.04576
```

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker. However averaging over the fitted values does not give me the same value as emmeans as I describe in the edit of my question.